# Realm table shows null data

Tags: android, realm

I have used Realm database and I want to store data from the JSON response into Realm. My JSON resoponse is something like,

```
[
    {
        "i_id": "108",
        "year_id": "122",
        "departments": [
            {
                "id": 164,
                "name": "Main Department",
                "classrooms": [
                    ......
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have two table first one is **OfflineResponse** and another one is **OfflineDepartmentResponse**, When first time **OfflineResponse** does not have data then it store data into **OfflineDepepartmentResponse** and also in **OfflineDepartmentResponse** but now I want to manually add departments into **OfflineDepartmentResponse**, It create null rows as you can see below image,

[image: Database Image]

Here is a code which I have written for the first time when all the data set is,

```
    int i_id = Integer.parseInt(offlineUserListObject.get("i_id").toString());

    if (realm.where(OfflineUserResponse.class).equalTo("i_id", i_id).findAll().size() > 0) {
        //This is where I want to store data manually
        realm.copyToRealm(realm.createObjectFromJson(OfflineDepartmentResponse.class, departmentObj));
    }else{
        //This data set for the first time and it is working fine.
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("offlineUserList", response);
        realm.copyToRealm(realm.createObjectFromJson(OfflineResponse.class, obj));
    }
```

Hope it does make sense or let me know for any clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
int i_id = Integer.parseInt(offlineUserListObject.get("i_id").toString());

if (realm.where(OfflineUserResponse.class).equalTo("i_id", i_id).findAll().size() > 0) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                      realm.copyToRealm(realm.createObjectFromJson(OfflineDepartmentResponse.class, departmentObj));
                }
            });
}else{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("offlineUserList", response);

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: What does make `realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()) ` difference ? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: when you want to copy or update something in your realm database, you have to give a sign that you are updating or copying something in your database. And the sign is `realm.executeTransaction()`. There is an alternative way too. You can add also, `realm.beginTransaction()` before copying and `realm.commitTransaction()` after copying object into realm database.

Comment: I have already added `realm.beginTransaction()` and `realm.commitTransaction()` in my method.

Comment: Unfortunately NO

Comment: It does not throw error, It simply creates new row with empty data as I have mentioned in Image

Comment: then, check your object that you are copying into realm??? Is that null???

Comment: Negative, It has all the data. It is actually same data structure which I have stored in first time but do not store it manually

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with JSON data, try to make a copy of online result and make some minor changes to data (so that the same objects are not update again) store it in a file and try to update that file as offline file. If its working, then its definitely something wrong with the offline Json file.